# converting .py to windows executable using cx-freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

when i try convert .py to windows executable this type of error 
Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/wininst-6.0.exe', /usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/wininst-6.0.exe not included in the Debian packages.

```
import sys
import os

from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
def find_data_file(password_lst):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:

       datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, password_lst)
    base = None
    includes = ['password_lst']
    zip_inc = ['password_lst']
    build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "include_files": includes, "zip_includes": zip_inc}

    setup(  name = "test",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "test",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("dummy.py" , base=base )])





   Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
   Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed
   error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:    '/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/wininst-6.0.exe',    usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/wininst-6.0.exe not included in the Debian packages.
```

Comment: cx_Freeze doesn't support building a Windows executable from a Linux system ([docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#freezing-for-other-platforms)). Shameless plug: you might be interested in trying [Pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: i tried but does't work any other module